# What does the “class” keyword mean within a member declaration?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine5

I'm currently learning C++ (for the Unreal Engine). I came across a piece of code in the sample code that I don't understand:

```cpp
class APangaeaCharacter : public ACharacter
{
    GENERATED_BODY()

public:
    APangaeaCharacter();

    // Called every frame.
    virtual void Tick(float DeltaSeconds) override;

    /** Returns TopDownCameraComponent subobject **/
    FORCEINLINE class UCameraComponent* GetTopDownCameraComponent() const { return TopDownCameraComponent; }
    /** Returns CameraBoom subobject **/
    FORCEINLINE class USpringArmComponent* GetCameraBoom() const { return CameraBoom; }

private:
    /** Top down camera */
    UPROPERTY(VisibleAnywhere, BlueprintReadOnly, Category = Camera, meta = (AllowPrivateAccess = "true"))
    class UCameraComponent* TopDownCameraComponent;

    /** Camera boom positioning the camera above the character */
    UPROPERTY(VisibleAnywhere, BlueprintReadOnly, Category = Camera, meta = (AllowPrivateAccess = "true"))
    class USpringArmComponent* CameraBoom;
};
```

It's about the lines that start with `FORCEINLINE class`.
Is a new class being declared here or what exactly does it mean?

Comment: Do you know what `struct Foo` means in a place where a type is expected? Related: [Difference between 'struct' and 'typedef struct' in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/612328/11082165)

Comment: Tells the compiler that `UCameraComponent` and `USpringArmComponent` are classes defined somewhere else. No need to know their implementation to declare pointers to them.

Comment: I'm not familiar with unreal engine but `class UCameraComponent*` in the declaration of another function _declares the type `UCameraComponent`_ in the namespace surrounding the declaration of the function

Comment: "Learning C++ [with] the Unreal Engine" is like trying to learn grade school physics by looking at the schematics of a Boeing 747. It's far more productive to invest 3-5 years with a reputable textbook that properly teaches and explains all core fundamental concepts of the hardest and most complicated general purpose programming language in use today, and only then branch out into learning and studying boutique, specialized domains like game engines.

Answer (score 5):

Update 10/04/2023: I think the name of the syntax is called [elaborated type specifier](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/elaborated_type_specifier)

---

The syntax you see tells the compiler that the type you are using is a class defined elsewhere. These classes are known as incomplete types. From [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/incomplete-types?view=msvc-170):

> An *incomplete* type is a type that describes an identifier but lacks information needed to determine the size of the identifier. An incomplete type can be:
>
> - A structure type whose members you have not yet specified.
> - A union type whose members you have not yet specified.
> - An array type whose dimension you have not yet specified.

You are seeing the first case: A structure type whose members you have not yet specified. (Note: `struct`s and `class`es are more or less the same thing in C++, with only subtle differences).

You can only use an incomplete type in a limited fashion. Creating a pointer to it is fine, and this is because an object pointer always have the same size (no matter what type it is pointing to).

---

As for why Unreal uses incomplete types in your class definition:

- It can help reduce compilation time. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3962708/how-much-do-forward-declarations-affect-compile-time). Note "forward declaration" in the referenced post involves the use of an incomplete type.
- It allows you to have headers referencing classes in declared in other headers. Imagine the following case (Unreal macros omitted for brevity):

```cpp
// FirstActor.h
#pragma once
#include "SecondActor.h"
class AMyFirstActor : public AActor
{
    AMySecondActor* Ptr;
}

// SecondActor.h
#pragma once
#include "FirstActor.h"
class AMySeoondActor : public AMyFirstActor
{
    FirstActor* Ptr;
}
```

The above example will not compile. Due to the presence of [`#pragma once`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard), the first header is actually expanded to:

```cpp
class AMySeoondActor : public AMyFirstActor
{
    AMyFirstActor* Ptr;
}
class AMyFirstActor : public AActor
{
    AMySecondActor* Ptr;
}
```

With out the `class` prefix before member declarations, the compiler will try to look for the actual definition of the class `FirstActor` when you say `FirstActor* Ptr;` but cannot find it up to this point. With the `class` prefix, the compiler will note its a type defined elsewhere and move on.

Another equivalent way to do this is to use the `class` prefix ahead:

```cpp
// FirstActor.h
#pragma once
#include "SecondActor.h"
class ASecondActor;
class AMyFirstActor : public AActor
{
    AMySecondActor* Ptr;
}

// SecondActor.h
#pragma once
#include "FirstActor.h"
class AMyFirstActor;
class AMySeoondActor : public AMyFirstActor
{
    AMyFirstActor* Ptr;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> It's about the lines that start with `FORCEINLINE class`. Is a new class
> being declared here or what exactly does it mean?

In some other languages we have the term "forward declaration" when you just declare the *existence* of something, without giving much details. C++ strictly doesn't use that term, but still a line

```
class UCameraComponent;
```

tells the compiler that such a class exists (somewhere). That knowledge is enough to be able to form a pointer `UCameraComponent*` or a reference `UCameraComponent&` to an object of that class.

Often such a declaration is used at the top of a header file, instead of including the (perhaps big and slow to compile) full declaration of the class.

If you want to be fancy, you can do the "forward declaration" and form a pointer in one go, as `class UCameraComponent*` ("there is such a class, and this is a pointer to it").

I wouldn't do that, as it is extra complicated and apparently confuses some readers.:-)

---

The macro `FORCEINLINE` looks like something that could be expanded to `__forceinline` on compilers that support this extension as a stronger "please inline this!" directive. It is not part of the C++ standard.