# C++ Mutual header inclusion and forward declarations

Tags: c++, header-files, forward-declaration

How do I allow two classes mutually include one another so they can convert from one to the other.

Car.hpp

```
#ifndef CAR_HPP
#define CAR_HPP

#include "Truck.hpp"
class Car
{
public:
    Car(int weight) : weight(weight) {}
    Car(Truck data) : weight(ConvertFromTruck(data)) {}

private:
    int weight;
    int ConvertFromTruck(Truck data)
    {
        ... //in real life there would be a lot more to transfer than just weight.
    }
}
#endif //CAR_HPP
```

Truck.hpp

```
#ifndef TRUCK_HPP
#define TRUCK_HPP

#include "Car.hpp" //Obviously won't be included because of the CAR_HPP include guard
class Truck
{
public:
    Truck(int weight) : weight(weight) {}
    Truck(Car data) : weight(ConvertFromCar(data)) {}

private:
    int weight;
    int ConvertFromCar(Car data)
    {
        ...//in real life there would be a lot more than just weight
    }
}
#endif //TRUCK_HPP
```

Main.cpp

```
#include "Car.hpp"
#include "Truck.hpp"

int main()
{
    Car newCar(42);
    Truck newTruck(newCar);

    return 0;
}
```

So obviously Truck.hpp can't truly include Car.hpp becuase CAR_HPP is already defined. Also, Truck.hpp can not forward declare `class Car;` because `Truck(Car data)...` requires a complete type, and a forward declared class is not a complete type.

It looks like this is similar: [Forward declaration being ignored?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32979842/forward-declaration-being-ignored) but there is no answer.

This topic states not to have mutual including headers. [Forward Declarations and Includes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3443026/forward-declarations-and-includes)

I would try to avoid this but how can I achieve a Car that can receive a Truck and convert it properly and a Truck that can receive a Car and convert it properly?

Is there a way I can use:
`operator Car() { ... }` and `operator Truck() { ... }` so that a Car can be casted into a Truck and vice versa?

Comment: Take a reference instead (e.g. `Truck::Truck(Car& data)`).

Comment: @Kevin: You'd want a `const` reference really,

Comment: Haven't looked at this in a few years. But with a bit more experience under my belt. I think in addition to the reference, the class needs to be forward declared.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the declaration

`int ConvertFromTruck(Truck data)`

`Truck` needs to be a *complete* type, which means that the class definition for `Truck` must be available to the compiler. And there lies your problem.

Fortunately there is a solution: pass the `Truck` by `const` reference:

`int ConvertFromTruck(const Truck& data)`

Here the compiler only requires an *incomplete* type for `Truck`, and a *forward class declaration* rather than the `#include` will suffice for that. This is very much superior at run-time too as you are not taking a value copy of the `Truck` when the function runs (although a compiler might optimise out that copy).

Do the same for the constructor (i.e. `Car(const Truck& data)`), and for the `Truck` class as well.

Note that I use a `const` reference as opposed to a non-`const` reference for two reasons (i) you **don't** want to be able to modify the object passed, and (ii) an *anonymous temporary* can bind to a `const` reference.

Comment: Oh that's great! It allows me to do what I want to do and passing by reference is more performant! Awesome! Thanks!

Comment: For (i) you said I want to be able to modify the object passed. Do I really want to modify the object passed? Wouldn't const make that object read only?

Comment: @Questionable: Oops, missed out a don't.

Comment: No problem! I thought that is what you meant but it never hurts to check.